# Let $f(x)$ be continuous at $x_0$. Let $S(d) = \sup_{(x_0 - d, x_0 + d)} f$, $s(d) = \inf_{(x_0 - d, x_0 + d)} f$. Prove $\lim_{d\to 0}(S - s) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity, supremum-and-infimum

Sorry for a bit unprecise title, the length is limited. Here is the full problem statement:

> Let $f(x)$ be a function continuous at $x_0$. Let:
>   $$
> S(\delta) = \sup_{(x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta)} f \\
> s(\delta) = \inf_{(x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta)} f
> $$
>   Prove that:
>   $$
> \lim_{\delta \to 0}(S(\delta) - s(\delta)) = 0
> $$

Let's define an arbitrary sequence $\{\delta_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ such that:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\delta_n = 0
$$
If follows that:
$$
S(\delta_n) = \sup_{(x_0 - \delta_n, x_0 + \delta_n)} f \\
s(\delta_n) = \inf_{(x_0 - \delta_n, x_0 + \delta_n)} f
$$
Observe that:
$$
s(\delta_1) \le s(\delta_2) \le \cdots \le s(\delta_n) \\
S(\delta_1) \ge S(\delta_2) \ge \cdots \ge S(\delta_n)
$$

We know that $f(x)$ is continuous at $x_0$. It means that for any sequence $\{x_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}$ such that:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = x_0
$$
we have that:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n) = f(x_0)
$$

Or combining the above:
$$
s(\delta_1) \le s(\delta_2) \le \cdots \le s(\delta_n) \le f(x_n) \le S(\delta_n) \le \cdots \le S(\delta_2) \le S(\delta_1) \tag 1
$$

Let $n\to\infty$ then:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} s(\delta_n) = \liminf_{n\to\infty} f(x_n) \le \lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n) \le \limsup_{n\to\infty} f(x_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty}S(\delta_n)
$$

Since $s(\delta_n)$ is monotonically increasing and bounded above, also $S(\delta_n)$ is monotonically decreasing and bounded below we might conclude that:
$$
\liminf_{n\to\infty} f(x_n) =  \limsup_{n\to\infty} f(x_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n) = f(x_0)
$$
Which implies:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}(S(\delta_n) -  s(\delta_n)) = \lim_{\delta\to 0}(S(\delta) -  s(\delta)) = 0
$$

I have doubts regarding the above. One of the points is: $x_n$ is an arbitrary sequence so $(1)$ must not necessarily hold, must it? I would like to kindly request verification of the proof and/or point to its weak parts in case it's even valid. If not could you please suggest a valid way to prove the statement?

Comment: The very last step, "Which implies:..." simply doesn't follow. Hint: Forget sequuences. Let $\epsilon>0$...

Comment: Is there something wrong with the post? I'm more than willing to maintain high-quality question here, so please consider adding a comment upon putting a downvote!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is unclear (to me) how $(x_n)$ is chosen such that $(1)$ holds, or why
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} s(\delta_n) = \liminf_{n\to\infty} f(x_n) \text{ and } \limsup_{n\to\infty} f(x_n) = \lim_{n\to\infty}S(\delta_n) \, .
$$

---

But the problem can be solved in a simpler way. $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, so for any $\epsilon > 0$  there is a $\delta_0 > 0$ such that
$$
 |x - x_0 | < \delta_0 \implies |f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon \, .
$$
It follows that for $0 < \delta < \delta_0$
$$
 f(x_0) \le S(\delta) \le f(x_0) + \epsilon \\
 f(x_0) \ge s(\delta) \ge f(x_0) - \epsilon 
$$
and therefore
$$
 0 \le S(\delta) - s(\delta) \le 2 \epsilon \, .
$$

---

Note that the reverse conclusion also holds: If $\lim_{\delta \to 0}(S(\delta) - s(\delta)) = 0$ then $f$ is continuous at $x_0$.